# multidimensional json parse in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How to parse json?

```
var text = '{"body":[
              {"name":"name","value":"test1"},
              {"name":"inquiry_type","value":"test2"}
            ]}'; 
console.log(text);
var obj = JSON.parse(text.body);
cosole.log (obj);
```

Here obj console displaying error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiline statements, use template literals. Your JSON string is text, once you parse it you will get an object on which you can access `body` property using dot notation or bracket notation.

```js
var text = `{"body":[
              {"name":"name","value":"test1"},
              {"name":"inquiry_type","value":"test2"}
            ]}`; 
console.log(text);
var obj = JSON.parse(text).body;
console.log (obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to extract `body` after you parse your JSON, not before.

```
var text = `{"body":[
          {"name":"name","value":"test1"},
          {"name":"inquiry_type","value":"test2"}
        ]}`; 

var obj = JSON.parse(text).body;
console.log(obj)  //note that you misspelled this too
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `text` is a multiline string you must use template string :

```
var text = `{"body":[
          {"name":"name","value":"test1"},
          {"name":"inquiry_type","value":"test2"}
        ]}`;
```

or write it in single line :

```
var text = '{"body":[{"name":"name","value":"test1"},{"name":"inquiry_type","value":"test2"}]}';
```

And you must save the parsed text in a variable like that :

```
var text = '{"body":[{"name":"name","value":"test1"},{"name":"inquiry_type","value":"test2"}]}'; 

text = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(text);
var obj = text.body;
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -3):

`JSON.parse()` takes a string of JSON and parses it, as the name suggests.

You have an array, not a string of JSON, so you don't need to do anything.